# Writing and image attachment to datastore as an avatar: Is it possible?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, google-cloud-datastore

Has anyone worked with attachments in received emails? I was thinking, instead of the user uploading an image they can send it as an attachment that I can use to upload to datastore.

The documentation has [sending attachments](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments.html) but I could not find any documentation about receiving attachments. [This page says](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html):

> attachments
>
> The file attachments for the message, as a list of two-value tuples, one tuple for each attachment.
>
> Each tuple contains a filename as the first element, and the file contents as the second element.
>
> An attachment file must be one of the allowed file types, and the filename must end with an extension that corresponds with the type. For a list of allowed types and filename extensions, see Overview: Attachments.

I think this is also about sending email.

I have this code to save the image to datastore:

```
class AvatarSave(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        q = User.all()
        q.filter("userEmail =", emailAddress)
        qTable = q.fetch(10)
        if qTable:
            for row in qTable:
                avatar = images.resize(self.request.get("img"), 50, 50)
                row.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
            db.put(qTable)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("user not found")

        self.redirect('/')
```

Intuitively, it seems that `message.attachment` instead of `"img"` will do the trick.

```
avatar = images.resize(self.request.get(message.attachment), 50, 50)
```

What do you think? Thanks.

---

**Update2** (New code as response to Nick Johnson's comment)

```
class Register(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        senderEmail = message.sender
        emailTuple = parseaddr(senderEmail)
        emailUserName = emailTuple[0]
        emailAddress = emailTuple[1]
        newAvatar = db.Blob(images.resize(goodDecode(message.attachments[0][1]), 50, 50))        
        newUser = User(userEmail=emailAddress,
                       userName=emailUserName,
                       avatar=newAvatar)
                   
        db.put(newUser)
```

---

**Update1** Problem solved:

For the record, and for anyone who has the same question please note that the [attribute of message](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) is `attachments` not `attachment`:

```
message.attachment
```

gives the `AttributeError`

```
AttributeError: 'InboundEmailMessage' object has no attribute 'attachment'
```

And the object `message.attachment` looks like this:

```
[('portrait.png', <EncodedPayload payload=#8461006914571150170 encoding=base64>)]
```

so the correct way to pull the `<EncodedPayload payload=#8461006914571150170 encoding=base64>` part is

```
avatar = images.resize(goodDecode(message.attachments[0][1]), 50, 50)
```

The original code that I posted has

```
avatar = images.resize(goodDecode(message.attachments[1]), 50, 50)
```

which does not work, obviously.

Thanks again to `jesmith` and `Robert Kluin` for answers.

---

**Update0** (regarding the answer by `jesmith`)

In my case, I am taking an image `"img"` from a form uploaded by a user and write it to datastore like this:

```
       for row in qTable:
            avatar = images.resize(self.request.get("img"), 50, 50)
            row.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)    
        db.put(qTable)
        self.redirect('/')
    else:
        logging.info("else user not found")
        self.redirect('/user-not-found')
```

In your code this corresponds to this section, I believe:

```
try:
    if hasattr(message, "attachment"):
        for a in message.attachments:
            msg.attachmentNames.append(a[0])
            msg.attachmentContents.append(append(db.Blob(goodDecode(a[1])))
        msg.put()        
except:
    logging.exception("exception decoding attachments in email from %s" % message.sender)
```

assuming that, in my case, there is only 1 attachment; how do I pick up the data part of the attachment?

Is it `message.attachment[1]` ?

```
avatar = images.resize(message.attachment[1], 50, 50)
```

is `message.attachment[1]` data part of the attachment?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using the email as the key name for the User entity? Your model permits duplicate users, and you fetch 10 of them, and update all of them with the avatar(?!) - this seems bizarre.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for pointing this out. I removed that code; because I realized that the user is just registering; I don't need to register the email of the new user; save it to database; and then pull it again to update the avatar. So now I do all in one pass. I am about to add an update and I would appreciate your comment on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fragment from an incoming mail handler I use:

```
   bodies = message.bodies(content_type='text/html')
    allBodies = u"";
    for body in bodies:
      allBodies = allBodies + u"\n" + unicode(goodDecode(body[1]), errors="ignore")
    if not allBodies:
      bodies = message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')
      for body in bodies:
        allBodies = allBodies + u"\n" + unicode(goodDecode(body[1]), errors="ignore")

    msg = EmailMessageModel()
...fill in various stuff...
    msg.sender = message.sender
    msg.date = datetime.datetime.now()
    msg.message = allBodies
    # Calling put() before dealing with attachments because it seems like that could throw various exceptions
    msg.put()
    event.email = True
    event.put()
    event.project.email = True
    event.project.put()
    # attachments is a list of element pairs containing file names and contents.

    try:
      if hasattr(message, 'attachments'):
        for a in message.attachments:
          msg.attachmentNames.append(a[0])
          msg.attachmentContents.append(db.Blob(goodDecode(a[1])))
        msg.put()
    except:
      logging.exception("Exception decoding attachments in email from %s" % message.sender)
```

Note that goodDecode is a function I wrote because there was a bug in the underlying GAE decode (it lowercased everything, which munged base64-encoded text):

```
def goodDecode(encodedPayload):
  if not hasattr(encodedPayload, 'encoding'):
    return encodedPayload
  encoding = encodedPayload.encoding
  payload = encodedPayload.payload
  if encoding and encoding.lower() != '7bit':
    payload = payload.decode(encoding)
  return payload
```

This is probably not necessary any more, because I'm pretty sure they fixed that bug.

In my case, I'm stuffing the attachments into the database:

```
class EmailMessageModel(db.Model):
....various stuff...
  sender = db.StringProperty()
  date = db.DateTimeProperty()
  message = db.TextProperty()
  attachmentNames = db.StringListProperty()
  attachmentContents = db.ListProperty(db.Blob)
```

When I want to show this email, I'm using this:

```
<h2>{{ e.sender }} {{ e.date|date:"M j, Y f A " }} GMT</h2>
<p>From: {{ e.sender }}<br/>Date: {{ e.date|date:"M j, Y f A" }} GMT ({{ e.date|timesince }} ago)<br/>Subject: {{ e.subject }}</p>
{% if e.attachmentNames %}
<p>Attachments: 
  {% for a in e.attachmentNames %}
<a href="/admin/attachment?email={{ e.key }}&index={{ forloop.counter0 }}" target="_blank">{{ a }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
{% endif %}
<div style='background-color: white'>{{ e.message }}</div>
```

The attachment handler is:

```
class AttachmentHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    email = EmailMessageModel.get(self.request.get('email'))
    index = self.request.get('index')
    if index:
      index = int(index)
      filename = email.attachmentNames[index]
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = str(mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]) or 'application/octet-stream'
      self.response.out.write(email.attachmentContents[index])
```

(So, basically, I'm letting the browser figure out what to do with the attachments.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. This is very helpful. I added an update with a question about how to adapt your code to my case. I appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Review the [Handling Incoming Email](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) section in the email docs, it explains the attachments attribute.

> The InboundEmailMessage object
> includes attributes to access other
> message fields:
>
> - attachments is a list of file attachments, possibly empty. Each
>   value in the list is a tuple of two
>   elements: the filename and the file
>   contents.

So you are going to want something like:

```
for file_name, data in message.attachments:
    # add some tests to check that the
    # file-type is correct and that the
    # data-size is "OK".
    avatar = db.Blob(data)
```

You will need to decide how you want to handle the case when a user attaches more than one image.  This will simply use the last of the attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in response to your follow-up:

> Is it message.attachment[1] ?

Yes, but you need to decode it.  Otherwise, you'll just get a big blob of ASCII characters (in emails, attachments are always encoded into a 7-bit, short line, 1975-safe format, such as base64).

```
avatar = images.resize(goodDecode(message.attachment[1]), 50, 50)
```

And don't forget to use lots of try-catch logic around it, because the mail stuff in GAE is prone to throwing lots of exceptions.